# What is the terminology for the Lorentz Force divided by charge?

Tags: electromagnetism

The Lorentz Force:

$$\vec{F} = q \left( -\nabla\phi - \frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) \right)$$

contains within it the "electric field"

$$\vec{E} =  -\nabla\phi - \frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t} $$

and a "magnetic field"

$$\vec{B} =\nabla \times \vec{A} $$

such that the Lorentz Force is more frequently expressed as:

$$\vec{F} = q \left( \vec{E} + \vec{v} \times  \vec{B} \right)$$

If one divides by charge, one is left with the subexpression:

$$\vec{?} = \vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B} $$

This $\vec{?}$ has a physically meaningful dimension commensurable with the "electric field" but it is not proper terminology to call it "electric field".

Being ignorant of the proper terminology, one might venture to call it the "motional electric field" or "electromotive electric field".

What is the proper term for this "field"?

Comment: I'm not sure this has a standard name. It would probably be most transparent to just call it "Lorentz force per charge".

Comment: @knzhou, how about "Lorentz force per charge with velocity $\vec{v}$"